# Raw Block data in Hexadecimals

Tags: blockchain, raw-data

Is there any Web API available for us to query Blockchain data in hex format?

The format should follow the standard (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block#Block_structure) structure rather than JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What kind of API do you want? Do you mean API with your local Bitcoin Core or do you need web-API?

Have a look to http://webbtc.com/block/000000000000000001f942eb4bfa0aeccb6a14c268f4c72d5fff17270da771b9 (this is an example)

It is possible to download block as [json] / [hex] / [binary] there if you know the hash of the block

UPDATE (december'17):
block in raw hex example : https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000000a7b4999c723ed9f308425708577c76827ade51062e135a?format=hex

Comment: At least webbtc is opensource, can set up own instance.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain Data API
https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api:

> Single Block
>
> - `https://blockchain.info/rawblock/$block_hash`
> - You can also request the block to return in binary form (Hex encoded) using ?format=hex

Answer (score 0):

Blockchai**r** has this api available that currently works (in 2022) https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_M31

Example for block `000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f`

https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/raw/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

and see the raw_block field